# jQuery unbind button while .animate() is running

Tags: jquery

I'm trying make a button unusable while animate running. I coded a simple scroll with the button but if a user clicks the button repeatedly, the animation doesn't stop so scrolling will repeat over and over. I tried using `unbind` on the element when clicked and `bind` 
again when the animtation had finished but it doesn't appear to work. Here is my code:

```
$(".go_up").bind('click',function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var $content_page = $this.siblings('.componentin').children('.item-page');
    var $content_math = $content_page.height();
    var $content_height = ($content_math)*(-1);
    var $content_margin = $content_page.css("margin-top");

    if (($content_margin) <= '0') {
        $this.unbind("click");
        $content_page.animate({ marginTop: "+=100px" }, "slow", function(){
            $this.bind("click");
        });
    }
});
```

And here is the example: [www.erincfirtina.com/bar/](http://www.erincfirtina.com/bar/)

[FIXED]

> ```
> $(".go_up").bind('click',function(){
>                   var $this = $(this);
>                   var $content_page = $this.siblings('.componentin').children('.item-page');
>                   var $content_math = $content_page.height();
>                   var $content_height = ($content_math)*(-1);
>                   var $content_margin = $content_page.css("margin-top");
>                   if ((($content_margin) <= '0') && (!$content_page.is(":animated"))){
>                   $content_page.animate({marginTop: "+=100px"}, "slow");
>                   }
>               });
> ```

added `.is(":animated")` and works smoothly

Comment: bind will take two parameters right?

Comment: May be duplaicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593195/how-do-i-rebind-the-click-event-after-unbindclick

Comment: Thanks. It works! I added ".is(":animated")" to if clause and it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//replace this: $this.bind("click");

with this:
$this.unbind('toggle').unbind('click');
```

Hope it helps

Comment: doesn't work. When clicked the element first time, code works but then button doesn't work. I think it stucked as unbind.

Answer (score 0):

Your second bind call doesn't give the function to call, so that is one problem

BTW, there is a great plugin for what you are trying to do called [accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/), it is in the jquery ui library which is also very useful. The cool thing is that also makes sure only one tab is open at all times (like the example you gave)

Comment: I'm using that for menu. The topic is scrolling the content with buttons.