# Rebind a unbind click

Tags: jquery, unbind

I am using this library that allows you to create a more elegant alert box (you can even use images!);
I used it with a click function and it works! A nice container opens with a close button, GREAT!
I noticed if you happen to click more than once on the link you assigned, it keeps firing. So multiple images begin to propagate. I used the unbind method, but it cancels the link permanently (until refresh etc.).

I was surprised to see the library doesn't compensate for this little problem, so I am wondering if you could rebind the click when you close the image window so it starts from the beginning.

```
$(".shopFrag").click(function(){
  Messi.img("_images/wishlist.jpg");                              
  $(".shopFrag").unbind('click');
});
```

Comment: which library, which framework, which operating system? is this about a web-application? please fix your description and tags so people understand the context of your problem.

Comment: I was using JQuery and Messi[link](http://marcosesperon.es/)on OSX 10.8.2 inside a webpage.

Answer (score 2):

There's a thread already open with this subject. If you're interested follow and read the solutions given:

[How do I "rebind" the click event after unbind('click')?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593195/how-do-i-rebind-the-click-event-after-unbindclick?rq=1)

Comment: Someone on the JQuery forum suggested the following.
$(".shopFrag").click(function(){
      if ( !$("place selector here").length ) Messi.img("_images/wishlist.jpg");                              
});